# Data fields missing in the splunk output

Tags: aggregation, timespan, splunk, bucket

I have two fields in my splunk data called as "impact_time" and "incident_name". Now i want to aggregate these incident names based on the "impact_time" and the span that i give. For example, 
If i give span as 1d, it should aggregate the incidents under each date.

```
2016-06-28 a,b,c,d
2016-06-29 g,r,w,d
2016-06-30 f,e,r,t
```

If i give the span as 1 hr, it should aggregate on the basis of hour from the impact_time

```
2016-06-28 03:00:00 a,b,c,d
2016-06-29 04:00:00 g,r,w,d
2016-06-30 05:00:00 f,e,r,t
```

I am getting this with the following query:-

```
index=sn impact=1 OR impact=2 | eval time = round( strptime(impact_start,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 0 )| where time >= ' + timeStart + ' AND time<=' + timeEnd + '| bucket time span=' + hm + ' | stats values(number) as incident_name by time
```

But there is one problem. When i keep the aggregation time as "hour", if in case an hour has no data, it doesn't show anything for that "impact_time". As in, the corresponding impact_time is completely missing from the data table. Is there any way it can show an empty "incident_number" field for an "impact_time" in case that "impact_time" has no data in it to show? For example:-

```
2016-06-28 03:00:00 a,b,c,d
2016-06-29 04:00:00 g,r,w,d
2016-06-30 05:00:00 f,e,r,t
2016-06-30 08:00:00 f,e,r,t
```

Here the time 06:00:00, 07:00:00 have no data. So these fields are missing from the data output completely instead of showing this:-

```
2016-06-28 03:00:00 a,b,c,d
2016-06-29 04:00:00 g,r,w,d
2016-06-30 05:00:00 f,e,r,t
2016-06-30 06:00:00 (null or empty)
2016-06-30 07:00:00 (null or empty)
2016-06-30 08:00:00 f,e,r,t
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `bucket time span=` approach, you can instead use the `timechart` approach:

I repro'd your scenario by running something similar on my data:

```
[...]
| bucket _time span=1h
| stats values(hostIdentifier) as hosts
```

This yielded:

```
-------------------------------------------
| _time            |    hosts             |
-------------------------------------------
| 2016-10-10 22:00 | host1, host2, host3  |
-------------------------------------------
| 2016-10-10 23:00 | hosta, hostb, hostc  |
-------------------------------------------
| 2016-10-11 00:00 | hostf, hoste, hostd  |
-------------------------------------------  <---This is the gap!
| 2016-10-11 02:00 | host4, host5, host6  |
-------------------------------------------
```

I then changed my query to use:

```
[...]
| timechart span=1h values(hostIdentifier) as hosts
| fillnull "hosts" value="No Host Data"
```

This yielded:

```
-------------------------------------------
| _time            |    hosts             |
-------------------------------------------
| 2016-10-10 22:00 | host1, host2, host3  |
-------------------------------------------
| 2016-10-10 23:00 | hosta, hostb, hostc  |
-------------------------------------------
| 2016-10-11 00:00 | hostf, hoste, hostd  |
-------------------------------------------
| 2016-10-11 01:00 |   No Host Data       | <---This _was_ the gap!
-------------------------------------------
| 2016-10-11 02:00 | host4, host5, host6  |
-------------------------------------------
```

If you leave out the `fillnull` stanza, it will just be a blank value in that cell.

I think this solution should work for your data set. The one thing is that Splunk uses built-in `_time` field for timecharting. You may need to overwrite the `_time` value to your own custom field a la:

```
[...]
eval _time=time
```

or just use the `_time` variable instead of `time` in all of your time calculations.

Hope that helps!

Comment: or you can rename the _time field in your output as 'time', or any other name:  your search text | rename _time AS time.  Doc link: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/SearchReference/Rename